# Ссылки на другие браузеры, если переходишь из фб

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть ссылка в фб которая ведет на мой сайт, и при клике - фб открывает свой браузер, и там открывает эту страницу.

И в фейсбуковском браузере получается открывается страница моя, а я хочу чтобы когда страница открылась в фб браузере - запросить у пользователя открыть страницу внешним браузером который есть на мобиле, хром, яндекс и т.д...

Как бы это реализовать на своей странице скрипта?...

---

Пользователь открыл страницу /fb.html из браузера ФЕЙСБУКА

С этой страницы, нужно перекинуть юзера на : /any.html НО не в этом фейсбуковом браузере, а запросить у пользователя: С помощью чего открыть эту ссылку...

Как это реализовать, какие может быть спец ссылки нужно вставить?...

Answer (score 0):

1. Нужно определить, что это браузер фейсбука.
2. И если это внутренний браузер фейсбука, попробуй эту показывать всплывающее окно с ссылкой вида:

`<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.bgg.com', '_system');">Go go go</a>`

3. Также можно попробовать добавить в ссылку `target="_blank"`